# Can I populate an AlertDialog with items from a sharedPreferences file?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I have set up the SharedPreferences like below:

```
Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.putString("chicago", "Chicago, IL");
        editor.putString("london", "London, UK");
            editor.putString("sanjose", "San Jose, CA");
            editor.putString("washington", "Dulles, VA");
        editor.commit();
```

At the moment I am populating the AlertDialog from an array, and I want to use the SharedPreferences file so I can eventually dynamically add items etc.

The code I use to populate at the moment is:

```
private void openServerDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)   
        .setTitle(R.string.server_title)
        .setItems(R.array.serverchoice, 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,
                    int i) {
                setServer(i);   
            }
        })
        .show();
    }
```

So I just want to stop using the array "serverchoice" and instead use the strings from the SharedPreferences file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getString() method of the SharedPreferences object to retrive a string from the shared preferences. See [the documentation for SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

**EDIT:**
Adjusted answer after a comment by the OP.

```
private void openServerDialog() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String, ?> sharedPrefsMap = sharedPrefs.getAll();
    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = sharedPrefsMap.values();
    CharSequence[] prefsCharSequence = stringArrayList.toArray(new CharSequence[stringArrayList.size()]);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)   
    .setTitle(R.string.server_title)
    .setItems(prefsCharSequence, 
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,
            int i) {
            setServer(i);   
        }
    })
    .show();
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of the getString method, I'd probably use getAll() as I'll be using all the items in the preferences file. I'm just unsure of how to use the getAll/getString method in conjunction with the AlertDialog code I have at the moment

Comment: See my edit. Is this what you were thinking? Note this code is untested.

Comment: thanks for the info! sorry for the delay in replying. I have added your code and it does grab the values and populates the menu items, however the list doesn't appear in the correct order. What determines this factor?

Comment: I should also say Eclipse recommended I change the code to the code shown in your example above

Comment: getAll() returns a Map, which doesn't give you a particular order. I would recommend reading up on data structures. A simple way to order the ArrayList would be to use Collections.sort(stringArrayList); This will sort your list of strings lexicographically. If you need to sort in a different way, you'll need to implement that yourself.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, and thanks for the information @Jeff, I'll research some more

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, you should mark it as such so others can see.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use getAll() method in SharedPreferences to get all the keys. And get all the keys and values and display in dialog.

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String, ?> map = prefs.getAll();
    Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
    for(String key : keys) {
        Log.d(TAG, "key : " + key);
            Log.d(TAG, "value : " + map.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: I really don't understand how that fits into my existing code. I am quite new to Android so I apologize for not understanding. 

I want to see the items in my Dialog to the values of everything in the preferences file. If you could explain a bit more about what the code above is doing that'd be really helpful

Comment: Okay what do you want to show in Dialog box..? If you want to show the list of existing keys - values in dialog so that user can add more items or delete existing item then you have to get the list of keys and values from SharedPreferences and store it in Map like above. Now before displaying the dialog, write your custom adapter which will show the list of keys with values (The values are retrieved by giving the key name in map) . Then do your functionality on clicking on the items. Link for SharedPreferences usage http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html